# Scroll subview to top inside UIScrollview iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

Anyone know how to scroll subview inside a scroll view to top of screen.
Like my scrollview have A B C D subviews, I want to show C on start of screen in iphone on the click of button.

Currently I am doing something like:

```
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.CView.frame animated:YES];
```